# Selenium - Robot Framework - Python - Page Should Not Contain Element not working

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am creating a new script where a setting is changed and then saved.  Once the save button is selected, the screen masks itself and a Please Wait... message displays in the bottom right hand corner of the page.  I want my script to wait for this message to no longer display and then logout.  The current behavior I'm seeing is that the scripts goes ahead and selects the logout button while the wait message is displayed.

I am using RIDE to edit my script and it looks like this:

```
Click Element   id=save
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds 30 sec  1 sec   Page should not contain element xpath=//*[text()='Please wait…']
${Status}   Run Keyword and return status   Page Should Not Contain Element xpath=//*[text()='Please wait…']
Run Keyword If  ${Status}=="True"   Click Element   id=logout
```

This test case runs successfully with no errors.  It just isn't waiting for the page to finish updating and the new setting to be saved.

Comment: what happens if you put a temporary `sleep` right after the `click element`? Perhaps the next keyword runs before the app has a chance to display the "please wait" message. Perhaps you need to first wait for the message to appear, and then wait for it to disappear.

Comment: Wow, I think that fixed it.  It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely that it takes your app several hundred milliseconds before the "please wait" message shows up. So, when the keyword runs until the page doesn't contain that element, the keyword immediately exits since it's not yet on the page.

A simple solution for this is to wait for it to appear before you wait for it to be gone:

```
Wait Until Page Contains element  xpath=//*[text()='Please wait…']  timeout=5
Wait Until Page does NOT contain element xpath=//*[text()='Please wait…']  timeout=30
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon the answer from @Bryan Oakley, the following is more inline with the example provided in your question. I've created a PoC using the following HTML page where the message will appear after 2 seconds from pushing the button and then vanish 5 seconds later:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please wait...";
    }, 2000);
 setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="save" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">save</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the below Robot Script I used similar keywords as @Bryan Oakley, but formatted it as well to make it more readable in SO.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    Open Browser    http://localhost:8090/waitfor/    browser=Chrome
    Click Element    id=save
    Wait Until Page Contains element     
    ...         xpath=//p[text()='Please wait...']    
    ...         5s
    ${Status}   Run Keyword and return status    
    ...                 Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   
    ...                        10s    
    ...                        1s   
    ...                        Page should not contain element   
    ...                            xpath=//*[text()='Please wait...']
    Run Keyword If   
    ...   ${Status}==${True}    
    ...    Log To Console    \n Status is True
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```